# How can I select the max value of a column based on other column values?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I'm looking at a table that is set up sort of like this:

```
Month  |  Year  |  Item  
1      |  2016  |  a
1      |  2016  |  b
1      |  2016  |  c
2      |  2016  |  a
2      |  2016  |  b
2      |  2016  |  c
3      |  2016  |  a
3      |  2016  |  b
```

The I want to get the highest month and year values when a, b, and c are all present, in this case 2, 2016.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Allowing for other values appearing in Item column, you could use:

```
SELECT TOP (1) Year, Month
FROM myTable
WHERE Item in ('a', 'b', 'c')
GROUP BY Year, Month
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT Item) = 3
ORDER BY Year DESC, Month DESC
```

If you are only ever going to have Item values of 'a', 'b' or 'c' then you can omit the `where` clause.